# Bootstrap dropdown content to the right of link

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, drop-down-menu

I am making a bootstrap mega menu in which the navigation was originally meant to be floating left. I have changed it to float right using the `pull-right` class provided by Bootstrap but now all my dropdowns are still appearing as if the nav was still floating left. How can I adjust the dropdown content to reflect the floating change?

Attached is an image of my problem:

[image]

As you can see the dropdown caret arrow pointing at Merchandising is off a little bit, which I can adjust. But the content of the dropdown should be to the right of the nav item, not the left. All bootstrap styles are default, except for the following CSS:

```
.dropdown-menu {
    position: absolute;
    top: 100%;
    left: -1px;
    z-index: 1000;
    display: none;
    float: left;
    min-width: 160px;
    padding: 10px 10px;
    margin: 0px 0 0;
    list-style: none;
    background-color: #fff;
    border-top: transparent;
    border-left: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, .1);
    border-right: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, .1);
    border-bottom: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, .1);
    -webkit-border-radius: 0;
    -moz-border-radius: 0;
    border-radius: 0;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
    -moz-box-shadow: 0 0px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
    box-shadow: 0 0px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
    -webkit-background-clip: padding-box;
    -moz-background-clip: padding;
    background-clip: padding-box;
}
```

Comment: "the content of the dropdown should be to the right of the nav item, not the left" -- but then it will be cutoff on the right... do you want the content to then stack vertically or page to scroll horizontally?

Comment: Actually, the image just makes it appear that way. The content needs to be pushed off the to the right.